# Newton Raphson method problem when iterating a variable

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I need help with a problem. I written a program to calculate the value of a function using the Newton Raphson method. However, the function also has a variable i would like to iterate over, V. The program runs fine until the second iteration of the outer for loop, then the inner for loop will not run further once it reaches the Newton Raphson function. If someone has any ideas of what is wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. The error i get is: Warning: Solution does not exist because the system is inconsistent.

The code is below for detail.

```
for V = 1:50;

syms x;

f(V)= Il-x-Is.*(exp((q.*(V+x.*Rs))./(1000.*y.*K.*T))-1)-((V+x.*Rs)./Rsh); 

g(V)=diff(f(V)); 

x0 = 0;

i = 1;

for i=1:10

        f0=vpa(subs(f,x,x0)); 

        f0_der=vpa(subs(g,x,x0)); 

        y=x0-f0/f0_der; % Newton Raphson

        x0=y;
end
end
```

Comment: Why are you using symbolic math for this, since you're only getting an approximation anyway, why not use numerical variables?

Comment: I haven't really consider any other option. Would you know how I could approach a numerical program for this?

Comment: Try `fzero`. Or use anonymous functions for `f` and `g` you you can do `f(x0)`.

Comment: I'm not really getting anywhere with fzero and anonymous functions... Do you have any concrete examples on how I could implement it?

Comment: The irony is, you've not given us a concrete example which you want to solve... please provide a [mcve] with expected outputs for given inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a function defined like

```
func = @(x,V) V+x+exp(x);
```

There are plenty of options that avoid expensive symbolic calculations.

Firstly, making a vector of values of `x0` using `fzero` and a `for` loop:

```
for V = 1:50
    x0(V) = fzero(@(x) func(x,V),0);
end
```

Secondly, the same thing again but written as an anonymous function, so you can call `x0(1.5)` or `x0(1:50)`:

```
x0 = @(V) arrayfun(@(s) fzero(@(x) func(x,s),0),V);
```

Finally, if you want to use ten steps of Newton's method and calculate the derivative symbolically (although this is not a great method),

```
syms y Vsym
g = matlabFunction(diff(func(y,Vsym),y),'Vars',[y Vsym]);

for V = 1:50
    x0(V) = 0;
    for i = 1:10
        x0(V) = x0(V)-func(x0(V),V)/g(x0(V),V); % Newton Raphson
    end
end
```

Which at least will be more efficient in the loops because it's just using anonymous functions.